# we can check whether intent.putExtras(key,value) has done or not?

Tags: android

I am working on android. i want to know that whether this is possible to check that 
following key,value pair has created or not ?

```
String filename=getIntent().getExtras().getString("FILE_NAME");
textView_file_name=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView_fileName);
textView_file_name.setText(filename);
```

before my first programing statement, means before getting the value of `FILE_NAME`, i want to check whether this key-value pair has build or not ? because i am getting null pointer exception in the case if it is not done before these statement. So i want to know that is any code so i can check `intent.putExtras().getString("FILE_NAME");` has done or not.

Comment: Getting an extra from an intent doesn't give you a nullpointerexception. All extras has default values if nothing is specified.
Please provide the stacktrace and please format your question correctly...

Comment: @Darwin But in case of String i think the default value is Null.So it may give NPE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store in a String variable if you send String data as below and print in cosole to check it:

```
Bundle b=intent.getExtras();
String str=b.getString("FILE_NAME"); //IF YOU HAVE STRING AS VALUE THEN USE getString() else use accordingly.
System.out.println(str);
```

Comment: i have resolved my problem by this code:-  if(getIntent().getExtras()!=null)
        {
     String filename=getIntent().getExtras().getString("FILE_NAME");
         textView_file_name=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView_fileName);
         textView_file_name.setText("Title : "+filename);
        }    
       i want to know such type of condition. thank you all...